# How to stop PageView rebuild on slide left right in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i want to stop PageView rebuild on slide left right.
basically i have 1 PageView with Horizontal Axis inside this PageView i have one more PageView with vertical Axis.

inside 1 Pageview i have only 2 children but in the second PageView i have http request based children.

**Problem** : when user scroll 1 PageView to right and then left then the 1 PageView rebuild the second Pageview children and set page index automatically to 0.

**Expectation** : simply i want to stop rebuild of 1 PageView when user scroll left to right then stop 1 PageView to that correct position and ignore to set position 0.

**Example of PageView**

```
return PageView(
  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
  allowImplicitScrolling: false,
  controller: _main_pageController,
  children: [
    PageView(
      controller: _pageController,
      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
      children: [
          for(int index = 0; index < complexTutorial.data.length;index++)
          COntainer(color:Colors.yellow),
                ],),
          
          // below is second child of 1 PageView.

         Container(child:Text("USER SETTING")),
          ],);
```

please help to resolve this issue i am new to flutter Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put the container inside a StateFulWidget then use [AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin-mixin.html)

and override the method 'wantKeepAlive' in the StateFulWidget

```
class YourStateFulWidget extends StatefulWidget with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin{


  @override
  _YourStateFulWidgetState createState() => _YourStateFulWidgetState();
}

class _YourStateFulWidgetState extends State<YourStateFulWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   
    return Container(
       child: Text("USER SETTING")
      
    );
  }

 @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => keepAlive;
}
```

Comment: firstly its not working with this class => class YourStateFulWidget extends StatefulWidget with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin                                                                                                                     its working with this class class _YourStateFulWidgetState extends State<YourStateFulWidget>  without any error but functionality not working with this class